# How can I place a text over YouTube flash player using JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, youtube, flash

I am building Chrome extension. I need to place a text over the YouTube flash player using JavaScript code. I saw many programmers did that but I didn't understand HOW?
***Update***: I need to place the text when the player been in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CSS and the `position` tag to place floating HTML elements. Note the YouTube flash player is just that, a flash object, so you can use normal HTML to place things on top of it.

You can read more [here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).

To manipulate the DOM (document model) with JavaScript you can use the [built in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_examples.asp) functions or use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: No, because **in full screen flash directly expands itself and renders the screen instead of the browser** thus it is IMPOSSIBLE to add stuff to it without using HTML5 and your own YouTube viewer.

Comment: Can you give me helpful links ?